# How to migrate WordPress to my own server(only home page is working other page goes to 404) How to fix?

Tags: wordpress, migration

**I have migrate the site from one host(wpengine) to my localhost(Linux server).**

1. I export and import the all data(Change the link also)
2. Moved all the file to local
3. Change the wp-config file

Only home page is working. Other page is not working. Other page goes to 404

Comment: Hi @Snow, please check your files and folder permission on your local server, files permission would be 644 and folders 755..
Also update your permalinks in Dashboard settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to set permalink again:

Go to:

**Setting -> permalink and set permalink. But make sure that your .htaccess file has permission to write.**

Answer (score 0):

after the weeks I found out the issue. It doesn't have file permission so I gave this permission it start working

chown www-data:www-data  -R * # Let Apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--